# Prove if $f(0)=1,\lvert Im\ f(z)\rvert<Re\ f(z) \forall z\in\mathbb{D}$, then $f'(0)\leq 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be an analytic function defined on the unit disk $\mathbb{D}=\{z:\lvert z\rvert<1\}$.

$f(0)=1$, and $\forall z\in\mathbb{D}, \lvert Im\ f(z)\rvert<Re\ f(z)$.

Prove that $\lvert f'(0)\rvert\leq 1$

Sorry I am not so familiar with complex analysis and I have no idea how to use the condition $\lvert Im\ f(z)\rvert<Re\ f(z)$. Any theorem or corollary about it will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @MartinR i don't think lack of context is bad... nearly all questions have the question posed and then some thoughts on it

Comment: well, I partially agree with @MartinR that the thoughts on the problem is important and shows my "sincerity". And I do that in my previous posts. But I totally have no idea on this problem :(. Anyway, lets focus on the question it self

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to replace $f$ by $g=F\circ r\circ f^2:\mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{D}$, where $r$ is the multiplication by $i$ and $F:\mathbb{H}\to \mathbb{D}$
$$F(z)=\frac{i-z}{i+z}$$
Here $\mathbb{H}=\{z\in \mathbb{C},\text{Im}(z)>0\}$ is the upper half plane.  We show that $g$ is well-defined and $g(0)=0$.

Since $|\text{Im}(f(z))|<\text{Re}(f(z))$, $\text{arg}(f(z)) \in [-\pi /2,\pi /2]$. Hence $\text{arg}(f^2(z))\in [-\pi,\pi]$. In other words, $f^2$ maps $\mathbb{D}$ to the right of the imaginary axis $P=\{z\in \mathbb{C},\text{Re}(z)>0\}$. Multiplication by $i$ (it is the same as rotation by $\pi/2$) transforms $P$ to $\mathbb{H}$, the upper half plane. Because $F:\mathbb{H}\to \mathbb{D}$, $g$ is well-defined. It is clear that $g(0)=0$.

Now $|g'(0)|\leq 1$ follows from [Schwarz's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma). But $g'(0)=-f'(0)$, we are done.

**Edit:** The illustration below is provided by Hagen von Eitzen. Note that the last map is $F\circ r$.

[image]

Comment: I took the freedom to add an illustration that I had begun to prepare to accompany a similar answer I was about to post.

Comment: Thank you! I also want to do it, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

There is a more theoretic solution as the condition $|\Im f| < \Re f$ implies $\Re (f^2)>0$.

Since $f(0)=1$ implies $f^2(0)=1$, the usual (Caratheodory, see below) coefficient bounds apply for $f^2$ so in particular the $z$ coefficient which is $(f^2)'(0)$ is at most $2$ in absolute value and this clearly implies $|f'(0)| \le 1$

If $g(z)=1+a_1z+a_2z^2+...a_nz^n+...$ is a holomorphic function on the unit disc with positive real part, then a classical theorem gives $|a_n| \le 2, n \ge 1$ with equality only for $\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ and its rotations

Comment: Correction: $|a_n-a_ma_{n-m}|\leq 2$ for $1\leq m<n$. See [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.6916.pdf)

Comment: The estimate above is classical (herglotz gives it immediately, but there are cool proofs using subordination and direct), but the paper linked is cool so many thanks!